# Jest renderIntoDocument not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I have a simple react app that only contains a Hello World react component and I want to test it with Jest.

Here's my simple hello world component

```
import React from 'react';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello world 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

And here's my test

```
// helloWorldTest-spec.js
jest.unmock('../src/components/HelloWorld');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import HelloWorld from '../src/components/HelloWorld';

describe('jest test', () => {

    const HelloWorld = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <HelloWorld />
    );

    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);   // just want the test to pass
    });
});
```

It will fail and return this

```
  runtime Error
  - TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined
         at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/helloWorldTest-spec.js:5:36)
    at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:375:17)
    at Runtime.requireModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:210:14)
    at jasmine2 (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:293:11)
    at Test.run (node_modules/jest-cli/build/Test.js:50:12)
    at promise.then.then.data (node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestRunner.js:264:62)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

 1 test suite failed, 0 tests passed (0 total in 1 test suite, run time 1.002s)
```

Has anyone ran into similar issue?

Comment: I ended up using `render()` instead after seeing this thread: https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/issues/116

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. It's a naming issue.

```
const HelloWorld
```

is the same as

```
import HelloWorld
```

Comment: are you able to go forward with this ? I was having almost similar issue but the "const Helloworld" is always null , and I couldn't go forward with this any further . any thoughts on this?